# Get application root URL and Directory name in Symfony 2 application

Tags: symfony

I want to know the root of the application both system eg. `/var/www/app/` or `/app/` for the purposes of file uploads. When I upload, I believe I need the "system" directory name, for use to links in web front end, I need the "relative" path. How do I get this information?

In a previous project, I defined constants in the `app*.php` files (front controller)

```
define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
```

Wonder if theres a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In any `ContainerAware` class you can get location of web directory by,

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->getRootdir().'/../web';
```

Comment: hmm ... I'm in my Doctrine model tho ... I guess I'll just use my old method. I should keep this in mind tho.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a good practice to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR as opposed to '/' for defining various paths, in case the project might be hosted on a windows environment?

Answer (score 9):

If the container is not available, you can use [dependency injection](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html): set `%kernel.root_dir%` as an argument to your class in the service configuration.